# How to add inputed value from input to the action of form?

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, jstl

I have a form which sends a request to the controller.

```
<form method="POST" action="/user/{id}">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Input Id">
    <button>Get User</button>
</form>
```

I need to add inputed value from  to the action of form. How can I do it? For example, if user input '2', my action must be action="/user/2".

UPD:

Can I use somthing like this (see below)?

```
<form:form id="myForm" method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" id="userId" placeholder="Input Id">
    <button onclick="setId()">Get User</button>
</form:form>
```

And script:

```
<script>
        function setId (){
            var id = document.getElementById('userId');
            document.getElementById('myForm').action  = '/user/'+id;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I need spring forms or jstl only.

Comment: Ok. How can I use js for my issue?

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701041/how-to-set-form-action-through-javascript).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, your example is looking js only, but not mention the tag in this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701041/how-to-set-form-action-through-javascript

Comment: @jmail I've said before you can only do this with Javascript. JSP and JSTL are server side components. The `ID` is input at the client side.

Comment: Well Said, @Sotirios Delimanolis , as always you do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to try this in Javascript as  Sotirios Delimanolis mentioned, try this

```
document.getElementById('form_id').action  = '/user/{id}'
```

ie:

Do this on button submit or window.onload or on, any other event handling,

```
var id = document.getElementById('inputfieldid').value;
document.getElementById('form_id').action  = '/user/'+id;
```

here is another example in SO using struts:
[Change action attribute of Form for different action methods in Struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661007/change-action-attribute-of-form-for-different-action-methods-in-struts2)

Note: In your case, you want the id from HTML input field, hence we have to go for javascript

Comment: I updated my question. Please check it. I added some js.

Comment: If I run it i'm getting 404 and url like this `http://localhost:8080/user/[object%20HTMLInputElement]`.

Comment: If I invoke val() on id, I'm getting 405 (Method Not Allowed).

Comment: var id = document.getElementById('userId').value;

Comment: document.getElementById('inputfieldid') gives the HTML element / object. We have to get the value out of it. I updated

Answer (score -1):

sample like this:

```
    <form method="post" action='UserController' >

        EMPLOYEE NAME: <input type="text" name="empName" 
            value="<c:out value="${user.empName}"/>"/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: And where is an id here?

Comment: What is this? What part of the question are you answering?

Comment: A sample that helps how?